# What does a variable in the right do in yield expression?

Tags: php

According to PHP documentation, a variable passed in `::send()` method of generator class is assigned to yield keyword.

it makes sense in following statement :

`$v = yield;`

But what about the statements like :

`$v = yield $a;`

yield keyword is already assigned and it shall return the variable passed into. Then what does `$a` do?

I've tried to figure this out and searched many posts and questions but none of them explain this.

Comment: You may want to do something with that `$v` afterwards, the code will run beyond that point.

Comment: Have a look at [this usage example](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.send.php#112729) (parentheses around `yield $i` are not required in PHP7)

Comment: @DanMiller I had read that page. what does the appending $i exactly do in the code you refer?

Comment: @ka_lin No I doubt that. Just look at the page dan just linked.

Comment: @Chyaamoo `$i` is the value that yields out of generator, and `$cmd` is the value passed inside so you can have more control on whats happening inside, on each iteration.

Comment: @DanMiller What is the difference between $cmd = (yield $i); and $cmd = yield; That's the point of this question. It's not clear why $i should appended.

Answer (score 0):

Answering by myself...

$v = yield $a;

meaning, first yield $a just as generally it does, then assign a variable passed by send() method to $v.

Still can't get clear explanation. But I think this is somewhat an answer of this matter.

Comment: Using `send()` defines `$v` whether you use `$v = yield $a;` or not, on second iteration `$v` would be set to `$a`.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Hmm... I don't get it. What youre saying is that this $a is stacked to be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Using `send()` will define `$v`, so if you use `$v = yield $a;` and before the iteration, you sent a value with send() it will yield the value which you sent it.

It can be hard to get your head around so here is an example, which creates two parts, the foreach iterator which loops over the generator and then on iteration 10 it sends a stop to the while loop. Then using getReturn gets the last value of the yield, like your `$v` in `$v = yield $a;`

```
<?php
$engine = function($callback) {
    $i = 0;
    while (true) {
        $state = (yield $callback($i++));
        if ($state == 'stop') {
            return $i;
        }
    }
};

$generator = $engine(function($i) {
    return $i;
});

foreach ($generator as $value) {
    echo "{$generator->key()} = {$value}\n";

    if ($generator->key() == 10) {
        $generator->send('stop');
    }
}

echo 'Stopped on: '.$generator->getReturn();
```

https://3v4l.org/dY8rV

**Result:**

```
0 = 0
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 4
5 = 5
6 = 6
7 = 7
8 = 8
9 = 9
10 = 10
Stopped on: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

The `yield` keyword can be used for three things:

- On its own, to return control temporarily to calling code. This is the basis of all the other uses.
- With a value after (`yield $foo`), to pass a variable *to* calling code.
- With an assignment before (`$bar = yield`), to receive a variable *from* calling code.

These are sort of similar to how you can use a function call:

- On its own, like `doSomething()`, to pass control temporarily to the definition of `doSomething`.
- With a parameter, like `doSomething($foo)`, to pass a variable *to* the function.
- With an assignment before, like `$var = doSomething()`, to receive a variable *from* the function.

You are hopefully quite familiar with writing `$bar = doSomething($foo);` to pass `$foo` to a function, and get `$bar` out afterwards. `$bar = yield $foo` is similar, but the value is passed "out" to the calling code, and the new value received back from that calling code afterwards.

`$foo` and `$bar` are not connected in any way, they are just the input and output of that particular `yield`. In the calling code, the `$foo` part of `yield $foo` or `$bar = yield $foo` can be accessed by calling `->next()` or `->current()` or getting the value in a `foreach`. The calling code *then* calls `->send()` with some value which becomes the `$bar` in `$bar = yield` or `$bar = yield $foo`.